# How to call CakePHP base application from plugin controller?

Tags: cakephp

I have a plugin, and add relationship with user Model(base application)
In the plugin view, I want to reference user's details based on user_id,

I get the user_id from plugin, but the url is pluginName/users/view/1

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($event['User']['username'], array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $event['User']['id'])); ?>
```

How to redirect to the App/users/view/1 ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You set `plugin => false` in the url array for it to use the "base" app.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($event['User']['username'], array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $event['User']['id'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `'plugin'=>null`

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link($event['User']['username'], array('plugin'=>null,'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view', $event['User']['id'])); ?>
```